# Make All Merges Manual in Git

Tags: git, merge, manual, merge-strategy

I need to know how to manually edit every merge. I found answers on here but everything is only when there is a conflict of merging. I implemented these and if there are new files pulled or no direct conflict between the code it will auto merge, which I can't have.

I want to manually OK every new file, line of code, and conflict with the mergetool.

Please help ive been trying to figure this out for more than a week.

Comment: Why would you want to manually merge every file?

Comment: Owner of the company wants us to submit our changes to him, he will manually approve everything and then push to production server. Just ensuring nothing gets overwritten which git can easily do if there are no conflicts thrown

Comment: The great thing about git, though, is that you can always go back to a previous version if the owner doesn't like the newest revision. So the owner could review after the fact instead of being a possibly time-consuming part of the process.

Comment: @JasonNicholas: Why not have him do the merge after he reviews changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `--no-commit` flag to `git merge`, git will execute the merge, but not make a commit of the proposed merge, so you can review it any way you'd like, including `git difftool`.

If you agree with the merge, do a regular `git commit`. If not, just work with the commit as usual until you're satisfied.

(By the way, as you've seen, Git will never automatically commit when the merge causes conflicts.)

Comment: I only recently learned about difftool and how to define which tool you would like to use. While I like the answer I've had quite a few times that after pulling with no commit and no ff, difftool does not open. Would you happen to know any cause for this? I have it in the config and it works fine sometimes.

Comment: "Sometimes" is a bit hard to debug without more context. You may have more luck asking a seperate question for that.

Comment: C:\Users\Chris\Documents\GitHub [master]> git pull --no-commit --no-ff -u testing master
    remote: Counting objects: 118, done.
    remote: Compressing objects: 100% (71/71), done.
    remote: Total 118 (delta 33), reused 87 (delta 25)
    Receiving objects: 100% (118/118), 11.24 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
    Resolving deltas: 100% (33/33), done.
    From https://github.com/NicholasJM/gitTesting
     * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
     * [new branch]      master     -> main_gca/master

Comment: used git difftool after this and nothing happens